# bad file descriptor: error on accept()

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to write a simple chat application, in which a client receives a string from the server and sends a new message, which will be delivered to the next client connecting. I am new to socket programming, and I really can't get why this error occurs. After the client sends his buffer, the server notifies an error on `accept()` (returning -1) and a bad file descriptor. Here's the code running on the server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    if ( argc < 2 ) {
        error("ERROR, no port provided\n");
    }

    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int cli_len, portno;
    char message[256];
    pid_t pid;
    int n;

    portno = atoi( argv[1] );
    bzero( (char*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr) );
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons( portno );

    sockfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

    n =  bind ( sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr) );
    if ( n < 0 ) {
        error("ERROR on binding\n");
    }

    listen( sockfd, 5 );

    do {
        cli_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

        int newsockfd;
        newsockfd = accept( sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr,(socklen_t *)&cli_len);
        if ( newsockfd < 0 ) {
            printf("%i", newsockfd);
            error("ERROR on accept\n");

        }

        pid = fork();
        if( pid == 0 ) {

            close( sockfd );
            sockfd = -1;

            n = send( newsockfd, message, strlen(message), 0);
            if ( n < 0 ) error("ERROR sending\n");

            bzero(message, 256);

            n = recv( newsockfd, message, 256, 0);
            if ( n < 0 ) error("ERROR receiving\n");

            close( newsockfd );
            newsockfd = -1;

        } 

    }
    while( 1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cli_len should be of type socklen_t, not int. The typecast hides a potential problem on x86_64 where int can be 32bit, but other size_related types can be 64bit.

Comment: You're not reporting the error correctly. You need to call `perror()` or `strerror()` *before* doing anything else that could change `errno`, such as `printf()`. Fix, retest, ...

Comment: Problem 2, the child should call exit when done, else both child and parent will fight in accept() ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child forked off should end after the `read()`, but it doesn't. It continues to loop. What probably is not your intention.

The child then calls `accept()` passing `-1` as socket descriptor. `-1` is not a valid socket descriptor.

```
    accept(sockfd, ...
```

The child sets `sockfd` to `-1` here:

```
    pid = fork();
    if( pid == 0 ) {

        close( sockfd );
        sockfd = -1;
```

Doing so the valid socket descriptor as returned by `socket()` gets overwritten, is lost.

So the error you observe does not arise from your listening server process, but from the forked-off child.

To fix this add a call to `exit()` inside the child, like this:

```
        ...
        newsockfd = -1;
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      }
```

---

This `int cli_len;` should be `socklen_t cli_len;`. And the cast of `cli_len` when calling `accept()` should be removed. Do *not* blindly cast away errors!

Answer (score 2):

If the result of `fork()` is zero you need to do your I/O with the accepted socket *and then exit the process*. At present you are allowing the accept loop to reiterate in the child process after having closed the listening socket.